# Test the input of the password

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am trying to test the functionality of view a password button, and to test the password that I already inserted. I guess that would be the easy part, the hard part is to actually click on the button to view the password. I am using rspec to run the test, and capybara to interact with mozilla firefox. This is the code of the password field, and view button that is located in the password field.

```
<span class="input-password-toggle-label" data-toggle="true" data-label-show="anzeigen" data-label-hide="verbergen" data-icon-show="<i class=&quot;icon icon-lg d-inline-block&quot;><svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 24 24&quot; class=&quot;d-inline-block&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; preserveAspectRatio=&quot;xMaxYMax meet&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;>
      <path d=&quot;M 12 5 C 6 5 1.3875 11.10625 1.1875 11.40625 C 0.8875 11.80625 0.8875 12.19375 1.1875 12.59375 C 1.3875 12.89375 6 19 12 19 C 18 19 22.6125 12.89375 22.8125 12.59375 C 23.1125 12.19375 23.1125 11.80625 22.8125 11.40625 C 22.6125 11.10625 18 5 12 5 z M 12 7 C 14.8 7 17 9.2 17 12 C 17 14.8 14.8 17 12 17 C 9.2 17 7 14.8 7 12 C 7 9.2 9.2 7 12 7 z M 12 9.5 C 10.619288 9.5 9.5 10.619288 9.5 12 C 9.5 13.380712 10.619288 14.5 12 14.5 C 13.380712 14.5 14.5 13.380712 14.5 12 C 14.5 10.619288 13.380712 9.5 12 9.5 z&quot;></path>
    </svg></i>" data-icon-hide="<i class=&quot;icon icon-lg d-inline-block&quot;><svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 24 24&quot; class=&quot;d-inline-block&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; preserveAspectRatio=&quot;xMaxYMax meet&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot;>
      <path d=&quot;M22.8,11.4C22.6,11.1,18,5,12,5S1.4,11.1,1.2,11.4c-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.8,0,1.2C1.4,12.9,6,19,12,19s10.6-6.1,10.8-6.4 C23.1,12.2,23.1,11.8,22.8,11.4z M12,17c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5s5,2.2,5,5C17,14.8,14.8,17,12,17z&quot;></path>
    </svg></i>" style="display: inline;" title="verbergen"><i class="icon icon-lg d-inline-block"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="d-inline-block" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" width="100%">
      <path d="M22.8,11.4C22.6,11.1,18,5,12,5S1.4,11.1,1.2,11.4c-0.3,0.4-0.3,0.8,0,1.2C1.4,12.9,6,19,12,19s10.6-6.1,10.8-6.4 C23.1,12.2,23.1,11.8,22.8,11.4z M12,17c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5s5,2.2,5,5C17,14.8,14.8,17,12,17z"></path>
    </svg></i>
</span>
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to click ok that view, thingy, button or something, to actually be able to see letters instead of ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your HTML has elements stored in attributes it makes it difficult to read exactly which are elements as opposed to strings, and which elements exactly you want to click on. Formatting your HTML better when posting a question would help in the future.  For this I think you're trying to click on the currently appended <i> element (I assume it gets swapped as the state changes) inside the outer span element.  You can do that with a basic CSS selector

```
find('span.input-password-toggle-label i').click
```

Comment: This actually worked, thank you, i will try to improve my HTML formatting while posting a question